# BeautifulSoup, change specific style attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to change only the background-color style with BeautifulSoup  :

My html :

```
<td style="font-size: .8em; font-family: monospace; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);">
</td>
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
soup_td = BeautifulSoup(html_td, "html.parser")
soup_td.td["style"]["background-color"] = "red;"
```

Answer (score 12):

That's a rather complicated answer above; you can also just do this:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'example'}):
    tag['style'] = "color: red;"
```

Combine the soup.findAll with whatever selector of BeautifulSoup you'd like to use.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since it overwrites the complete 'style' tag instead of changing only a single value.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`cssutils`](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/README.html#documentation) to manipulate CSS, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from cssutils import parseStyle

html = '<td style="font-size: .8em; font-family: monospace; background-color: rgb(244, 244, 244);"></td>'

# Create soup from html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Parse td's styles
style = parseStyle(soup.td['style'])

# Change 'background-color' to 'red'
style['background-color'] = 'red'

# Replace td's styles in the soup with the modified styles
soup.td['style'] = style.cssText

# Outputs: <td style="font-size: .8em; font-family: monospace; background-color: red"></td>
print(soup.td)
```

You could also use regex if you're comfortable with using it.